# Any ideas to optimize MySQL query with JOIN GROUP and ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query below.

```
SELECT `user`.id, title, something, SUM(cnt) AS `total`, 
FROM `user` 
LEFT JOIN `stat_per_day` ON stat_per_day.user_id = user.id  
WHERE CAST(stat_per_day.created_at AS DATE) BETWEEN '2017-08-12' and '2017-09-12'
GROUP BY `user`.`id` 
ORDER BY `total` DESC 
LIMIT 250;
```

Both tables has approx. 500k records.

Table `stat_per_day` structure:

`id | created_at | user_id | cnt`

I'm trying to use indexes, but does not get speed up.
The problem is that I need to receive ordered data for an any period.
Also, if i remove `ORDER BY` it runs faster, but i need this order.

Any ideas?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following might help a bit:

```
SELECT u.id, u.title, u.something,
       (SELECT SUM(spd.cnt)
        FROM stat_per_day spd
        WHERE spd.user_id = u.id AND
              spd.created_at >= '2017-08-12' AND
              spd.created_at < '2017-09-13'
       ) AS total
FROM `user` u
ORDER BY total DESC 
LIMIT 250;
```

An index on `stat_per_day(user_id, created_at, cnt)` will help with performance.

Comment: Thank you, it works on 50% faster. But what if i need to get more SUM() columns from stat_per_day, like SUM(cnt2)? I have a "Operand should contain 1 column(s)" error, but make a lot of sub-selects is slowly.

Comment: @Walkboy . . . You would have a different question.  You might try a second subquery in the `SELECT`.  Depending on the data, it might not have that big an affect on performance.

Comment: Unfortunately adding subquery kills a speed up effect.